# Why Ul upper white space

Tags: html, css

When I put unordered list

then why top bar goes down ?? I cannot find the reason behind this.Please tell me how to fix this problem ?

http://jsfiddle.net/fLchtkp1/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.top-bar {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#menu {
  width: 1020px;
  height: : 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
ul {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="top-bar">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>Menu1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The ul element has margin-top by default from browser. To remove that, add the style

```
ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this for removing `padding` and `margin` which is given by browsers

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

you will get more information on reset css [**here**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

here are the list of css styles used to reset

http://www.cssreset.com/